# How should I modify a welder to add a pedal to enable the output?

Tags: switches, high-current

I'm restoring/improving an old welder rated 3.2 kW input, 115 A DC output, 52 V no load.

I'm adding a ready made soft-start circuit based on a NTC plus bypass relay rated 100 A and capacitors to correct the power factor at half output power (about 2.5 kVAR, 10 A at no load).

I am evaluating adding a bypass (thyristor, triac, or heavy duty relay) to the rectifier on the secondary to obtain, when needed, AC output, preferred for some use cases, and a capacitor in parallel with the output to enhance the starting of the arc.

I'm not an experienced welder so I would like to add a pedal switch to enable the output to the electrode only upon need and avoid inadvertently starting the arc before I wear eye protection.

Edit: a way to quickly cut the current when an electrode sticks to the piece would also be useful, but in this case a significant current has to be stopped.

My options are:

- switch the primary winding of the transformer, causing each time a significant inrush, but also avoiding the heating from the constant reactive current of the capacitors for the soft start relay and plug. The NTC would be more stressed (the time constant is usually two minutes), but the relay would stay cooler;
- switch the secondary of the transformer, which would however require a high current component (thyristor, triac, or heavy duty relay).

Is my worry about the primary motivated or irrelevant? are there other factors to consider?

Comment: Consider that if you switch the primary and the switch and your foot is wet.... Better that you get used to staring the arc once you have the shield in place, that's what welders do...

Comment: @SolarMike sure, but the first time you touch the piece with the electrode, or you hit something that is on the table, which touches the electrode... and an arc starts, you may have a hole in the retina forever. I heard stories of welders which have to live with a "fly" always in their field of view due to this! The foot switch would operate on a low voltage to activate a main relay! no 230V of course. But I have to guess that you would go for the primary, not the high voltage secondary circuit?

Comment: I have worked with welders with diving qualifications and they were never concerned about this... May be with cowboys who try with green glass bottles but those with proper gear, never ...

Comment: Learning proper welding technique would eliminate the need for a foot switch altogether, and means you'd have little trouble operating any other similar machine if the need arose.